# Code in VBA to have an InputBox pop up, choose a folder, and have DOCX files deleted

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to make a small program that converts .RTF files to .DOCX. I have managed to do this part. Now, I want to add an Input box to delete the .RTF files in that same folder.

I do not want to input the location manually every time I have to do a new folder.

Is there any way to have the .RTF files from the same folder deleted when I run the program

OR

is there a way to choose the location in a Input Box.

CODE:

```
Sub ChangeRTFTODOCXOrTxtOrRTFOrHTML()
'with export to PDF in Word 2007
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim tFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim locFolder As String
    Dim fileType As String
    Dim locFolderKill As String

    On Error Resume Next
    locFolder = InputBox("Enter the folder path to RTFs", "File Conversion", "")
    Select Case Application.Version
        Case Is < 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change rtf to TXT, RTF, HTML, DOCX", "File Conversion", "DOCX"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML" Or fileType = "DOCX")
        Case Is >= 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change rtf to TXT, RTF, HTML, DOCX or PDF(2007+ only)", "File Conversion", "DOCX"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML" Or fileType = "PDF" Or fileType = "DOCX")
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder)
    'Set tFolder = fs.CreateFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
    'Set tFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Dim d As Document
        Set d = Application.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)
        strDocName = ActiveDocument.Name
        intPos = InStrRev(strDocName, ".")
        strDocName = Left(strDocName, intPos - 1)
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory tFolder
        Select Case fileType
        Case Is = "DOCX"
            strDocName = strDocName & ".DOCX"
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
        Case Is = "TXT"
            strDocName = strDocName & ".txt"
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText
        Case Is = "RTF"
            strDocName = strDocName & ".rtf"
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF
        Case Is = "HTML"
            strDocName = strDocName & ".html"
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatFilteredHTML
        Case Is = "PDF"
            strDocName = strDocName & ".pdf"

            ' *** Word 2007 users - remove the apostrophe at the start of the next line ***
            'ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strDocName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

        End Select
        d.Close
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory oFolder
    Next oFile
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'This is where I want to insert the InputBox to delete the .RFT files.


    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\Users\maciasa\Desktop\main test\test RFTs\*.rtf"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

1. List item

Comment: Why on Earth would you use an `InputBox` to prompt for a path/filename? Use `Application.GetOpenFilename` to present a full-featured browse box to the user.

Comment: Is there a way to select the folder and then have it Kill .RTF files? maybe in a IF statement?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to allow the user to pick a folder in a more user-friendly way:

**EDIT** - added deleting the files

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim folderDialog As FileDialog, fld As String, numDel
    Set folderDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    folderDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    'user picked a folder?
    If folderDialog.Show() Then
        fld = folderDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        numDel = DeleteFiles(fld, "*.rtf")
        MsgBox numDel & " files deleted from: " & vbLf & fld
    End If

End Sub

Function DeleteFiles(theFolder As String, fileType As String) As Long
    Dim f, col As New Collection, rv As Long
    If Right(theFolder, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        theFolder = theFolder & Application.PathSeparator
    End If
    'collect all matching files in the folder
    f = Dir(theFolder & fileType, vbNormal)
    Do While f <> ""
        col.Add theFolder & f
        f = Dir()
    Loop
    rv = col.Count
    For Each f In col
       Kill f
    Next f
    DeleteFiles = rv '<<return number of files deleted
End Function
```

Comment: Is there a way to select the folder and then have it Kill .RTF files? maybe in a IF statement?

Comment: @isaac well you have the folder with `path = folderDialog.SelectedItems(1)`, so you just need to verify that a folder was indeed selected, and then do `Kill path & "\*.rtf"` and call it a day. BTW get rid of `On Error Resume Next` if you want to be able to troubleshoot your code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - updated (but I went the long way around deleting the files...)